# Breeze executeLocally gives error 'undefined is not a function'

Tags: breeze, local

I'm trying to use the execute locally feature in breeze and it's giving me the error 'undefined is not a function'. Following is the two functions - in first one, I retrieve the data from the database and in the second one I try to get the data from the local cache.

```js
 function getServices(clientId, currentLocation, activeStatus) {
   var self = this;

   var Predicate = breeze.Predicate;
   var whereClause = Predicate.create("activeStatus", "==", parseInt(activeStatus));

   return EntityQuery.from('Services')
                                .withParameters({ clientId: clientId, currentLocation: currentLocation })
                                .where(whereClause)
                                .expand("Location")
                                .using(self.manager)
                                .execute()
                                .then(querySucceeded, this._queryFailed);

   function querySucceeded(data) {
    if (data.results.length > 0) {
        services = data.results;
    }
    logSuccess(localize.getLocalizedString('_RetrievedHolidays_'), services, true);
    return services;
   }
  }

function getServicesLocally(clientId, currentLocation, activeStatus, category, type, includeSubLocations) {
      var self = this;
      services = [];

      var Predicate = breeze.Predicate;
      var p1 = Predicate.create("activeStatus", "==", parseInt(activeStatus));
      var p2 = Predicate.create("fkServiceTypeId", "==", parseInt(type));
      var p3 = Predicate.create("fkServiceCategoryId", "==", parseInt(category));
      var whereClause = p1;
      if (type != 0)
          whereClause = whereClause.and(p2);
      if (category != 0)
          whereClause = whereClause.and(p3);


      return EntityQuery.from('Services')
                                .withParameters({ clientId: clientId, currentLocation: currentLocation })
                                .where(whereClause)
                                .orderBy('location.fkLocationTypeId')
                                .using(self.manager)
                                .executeLocally()
                                .then(querySucceeded, this._queryFailed);

      function querySucceeded(data) {
          if (data.results.length > 0) {
              services = data.results;
              //if sub-locations are to be ommitted, remove the services of the sub-locations
              if (!includeSubLocations) {
                  services = removeServicesOfSubLocationsFromServiceList(services);
              }
          }
          logSuccess(localize.getLocalizedString('_RetrievedHolidays_'), services, true);
          return services;
      }
  }
```

Following is the API call that retrieve the services:

```js
 [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable Services(int clientId, int currentLocation)
        {
            locationsRepo = new ClientLocationsRepository(this.CurrentUser, this.SystemContextProvider, clientId);
            serviceRepo = new ClientServiceRepository(this.CurrentUser, this.SystemContextProvider, clientId);

            int currentLocationType = locationsRepo.GetLocationType(currentLocation).LocationTypeId;
            List<Location> accessibleLocationList = GetLocationsAccessible(clientId, currentLocation).ToList();
            IQueryable productsAndServices = serviceRepo.GetProductsAndServices(accessibleLocationList, currentLocationType);
            return productsAndServices;
        }
```

Comment: Which query is giving you the error and where? IMPORTANT: the `withParameters` clause is only useful when talking to the server as it's purpose is to add parameters to the request URL; I believe it is ignored (or should be ignored) when querying the cache (querying locally).

Comment: getServicesLocally() this is what gives the error. You are right, I wouldnt need the withparameters for the local query.

Answer (score 1):

because the method you are using to query cache locally is giving the error "undefined is not a function".Use this method while querying cache locally

```
manager.executeQuery(query).then(function(data) {
    var query2 = query.where(predicate)
                .using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache);
    manager.executeQuery(query2).then(function(dataSubset) {
      // use your datasubset to populate your results....  
    });
```